# Bittorrent crashes on startup

Tags: macos, crash

I am running OS X Yosemite, and every time I try to open Bittorrent, it crashes. I can't think what has brought on this problem, but it was working fine before.
I have attached a log file for you to look at, I am not very experienced in this kind of thing. I have tried reinstalling it, and removing the preferences file in ~/Library/Preferences/ but that has not worked.

Sorry if I have missed anything, I am new to these forums.
Thanks

Log File: http://pastebin.com/s1zgqQdC

Comment: You did everything correct in asking, but where is the attachment log file ?

Comment: Sorry, sorry! Forgot to add it, i've added it now

Comment: OK, got it, you have 7.4.3 ? is that beta? do you have  1-13-2015: Version 7.4.2 (Build 37980) Stable